# Summation of L1-function values finite

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sampling-theory

For $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, we can proof, that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |f(t+na)|<\infty$ ALMOST EVERYWHERE for $t\in [0,a]$

($\star$ proof below)

My Question: If we assume $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C(\mathbb{R})$, can we conclude
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |f(t+na)|<\infty \text{ for all }t\in [0,a]\ \ \ ?$$

I would especially need to show: $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |f(na)|<\infty$

---

$\star$ proof:

Define $f_n=\chi_{(na,(n+1)a]}\cdot f \Rightarrow\ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|f_n|=|f|\ \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

If we use monotone convergence and shifting invariance of the Lebesgue integral we get:
$$\infty>\int_\mathbb{R} |f(t)|dt=\int_\mathbb{R}\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|f_n(t)|dt = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\int_\mathbb{R}|f_n(t)|dt=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\int_{(na,(n+1)a]}|f(t)|dt=$$
$$=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\int_0^a|f(t+na)|dt=\int_0^a\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|f(t+na)|dt$$
So we can conclude: $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|f(t+na)|<\infty$ a.e. for $t\in[0,a]$

Comment: I'm curious for the assertion in the first line. Could you show me a proof?

Comment: I just added the proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not true, it would still be for allmost all $a$. As a counter example consider $a=1$ and $f$ given such that $f(n)=1$ but $\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

If you need me to elaborate a bit more leave a comment.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. So even for $f\in L^1 \cap C^\infty$ we could construct such a counterexample...

Comment: Exactly and even easily

Comment: Maybe I have to say something more to my problem. Actually I am looking at bandlimited $f\in L^1$, i.e. $supp(\hat{f})\in [-\lambda,\lambda]$. Therefore Parley-Wiener tells us, that $f\in C^\infty$ and also of exponential type: $f(\xi)<Ce^{2\pi \lambda|\xi|}$ . 

But nevertheless I think  your counterexample will apply.